# add maxlength to form_tag in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I can't seem to get this syntax working. I want to restrict this to a max length of 3 character.

`<%= number_field_tag "foo[bar]" %>`

My approach which isn't working is 
`<%= number_field_tag "foo[bar]", :maxlength =>3 %>`

thank you in advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation:

- http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/number_field_tag

You should use it this way:

```
number_field_tag "foo[bar]", nil, :max_length => 3
```

Or like this:

```
number_field_tag "foo[bar]", nil, :in => 0..999
```

Comment: I got the second one working:
`number_field_tag "foo[bar]", nil, :in => 0..999`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use it just fine as the `number_field_tag` accepts all the options of `text_field_tag` (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_field_tag).

This typo should be the reason why it's not working.

Use `:maxlength => 3` not `:maxlenght => 3`.

**Update:**

The second parameter to the `number_field_tag` is `value` which you could either set to `nil` or `empty` as follows (As also pointed by MrYoshiji in his answer):

```
<%= number_field_tag "foo[bar]", '', :maxlength =>3 %>
```

Comment: that was a Stackoverflow typo, I just edited it. that is not the issue

Comment: @lando2319, I've added an update to my answer.  Please see above.

Answer (score 0):

`<%= number_field_tag("foo[bar]", "some value", {maxlength: 3}) %>`